# Matrices - Prove A and B are symmetric 2 x 2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are both symmetric 2x2 matrices, then $A$ + $2B$ is also a symmetric matrix.

The problem I have with this question is proving. How do I prove that? All I understand to do is show an example, but that's not allowed.

Any help?

Comment: What does it mean for a matrix $M$ to be symmetric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symmetric means $A^T=A$ and $B^T=B$. Now $(A+B)^T = A^T + B^T = A + B$ means $A+B$ is symmetric. Try the same sort of thing with $A+2B$

Comment: Or with $rA + sB$, or with $\sum_{i=1}^n r_i A_i$

Answer (score 1):

Note that a matrix $C$ is symmetric if $C^T=C$.

$(A+2B)^T=(A^T+2B^T)=A+2B$ as $A$ and $B$ are symmetric.

(I assumed that the matrices are over reals.)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** What happens to the seperate elements $a_{ij}$ and $b_{ij}$ when you add them together? And what do you know of them from the fact that $A$ and $B$ are symmetric?